react dom content to pdf is creating very large size pdf reacrjs jsdoc
I have a page rendered in reactjs that contains simply some paragraphs and one logo with some styles and i want to export it as pdf document.
So for this I am usinng
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

const generatePdf = async () => {
    const element = contentRef.current;
    const canvas = await html2canvas(element, { scale: 2 });
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    const imgBlob = await fetch(imgData).then(res => res.blob());
    saveAs(imgBlob, 'document.png');

    // A4 size dimensions in pixels
    const pdfWidth = 210; // A4 width in mm
    const pdfHeight = 297; // A4 height in mm

    // Get dimensions of the canvas
    const canvasWidth = canvas.width;
    const canvasHeight = canvas.height;

    // Convert dimensions to mm for jsPDF
    const imgWidth = pdfWidth;
    const imgHeight = (pdfWidth / canvasWidth) * canvasHeight;

    const pdf = new jsPDF({
      orientation: 'portrait',
      unit: 'mm',
      format: 'a4',
    });

    // If the image height exceeds the page height, handle multi-page PDF
    if (imgHeight > pdfHeight) {
      let yPosition = 0;
      while (yPosition < imgHeight) {
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, -yPosition, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        yPosition += pdfHeight;
        if (yPosition < imgHeight) {
          pdf.addPage();
        }
      }
    } else {
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    }

    // Save the PDF for preview or testing
    // pdf.save("document.pdf");

    // Convert Blob to File
    const pdfBlob = pdf.output('blob');
    const file = new File([pdfBlob], 'document.pdf', { type: 'application/pdf' });

    return file;
  };

and on the same page there is a signature component
import SignatureCanvas from 'react-signature-canvas';

where user can sign and then can download that document
everything is working fine but created pdf is almost 40mb
can we reduce the size and instead of creting image can we direcly export as pdf?
